# Disable Gravity for certain physic bodies

Tags: lua, love2d

How can I disable gravity for certain physic bodies using LOVE Physics for Lua?

```
blocks.ground.body = love.physics.newBody(world, 0, blocks.ground.y, "dynamic")
blocks.ground.shape = love.physics.newRectangleShape(500, 50)
blocks.ground.fixture = love.physics.newFixture(blocks.ground.body, blocks.ground.shape)
blocks.ground.color = {86,176,0}
```

That is my current code for the body, I also need it to stay "dynamic" because I need to move its X

**View Full Code:** [code](https://hastebin.com/ofusilozim.lua)

Comment: Can you post more code?  Such as how you defined the sets.

Comment: https://hastebin.com/ofusilozim.lua I know it is not the nicest looking code, but this is one of my first lua games so I am still learning

Comment: That's fine.  Its a fun language to learn.  Its useful to be able to look at the full code though.  I recommend adding that line to your question such as **View Full Code:** --> link

Comment: Please include a minimal executable example inside the question instead of linking to an external website. External links are prone to bitrot and might not work in the future. For more info, see [this discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339450/should-code-from-pastebin-be-edited-into-a-question) on Meta.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using **LÖVE 0.8.0+:**

**Option 1:**

**Your Code:**

```
blocks.ground.body = love.physics.newBody(world, 0, blocks.ground.y, "dynamic")
blocks.ground.shape = love.physics.newRectangleShape(500, 50)
blocks.ground.fixture = love.physics.newFixture(blocks.ground.body, blocks.ground.shape)
blocks.ground.color = {86,176,0}
```

**Note:** In your code `love.physics.newFixture(blocks.ground.body, blocks.ground.shape)`

**From LOVE's Website (1):**

```
objects.ground.fixture = love.physics.newFixture(objects.ground.body, objects.ground.shape) --attach shape to body
```

**Also from LOVE's Website (2):**

```
objects.ball.fixture = love.physics.newFixture(objects.ball.body, objects.ball.shape, 1) -- Attach fixture to body and give it a density of 1.
```

In the second snippet from their website they set the balls density (*mass*) to `1`.  Similarly you should be able to set the mass to `0` in which case gravity would have no affect on the object.  However if other objects collide with your object, of mass `0`, I am not sure what type of funky actions may occur.

**Option 2:**

The other option is to create a new world with gravity of `0`:

```
love.physics.setMeter(64) --the height of a meter our worlds will be 64px
  worldNoGravity = love.physics.newWorld(0, 0, true)
```

Then add the bodies to that world:

```
blocks.ground.body = love.physics.newBody(worldNoGravity , 0, blocks.ground.y, "dynamic")
blocks.ground.shape = love.physics.newRectangleShape(500, 50)
blocks.ground.fixture = love.physics.newFixture(blocks.ground.body, blocks.ground.shape)
blocks.ground.color = {86,176,0}
```

Hope one of those will work for you :).